# $\prod_i V_i$ is also a sub space of $B(H,K)$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

> Suppose $V_i$ are subspaces of $B(H_i,K_i)$. Is it true that $\prod_i V_i$ is also a sub space of $B(H,K)$ for some appropriate $H$ and $K$?

I think we need to take $H$ and $K$ to be direct product of $H_i$ and $K_i$ respectively but I am not sure. Can somebody help me?

Comment: What type of spaces are $H_i, K_i$? Normed? If there is only finitely many of them the answer is true. Otherwise, there are different ways to define the norm of their direct sum (e.g $\ell _1$, $\ell _\infty$ are different). And I am not sure what you mean.